# Check website availability in c#

Tags: c#, webrequest

In my WPF application, I need to check the availability of a website at regular interval.

I have this code :

```
public static string CheckWebsiteAccessibility(Uri uri)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Timeout = 15000;
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    return response.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

That I call every 30 seconds. In localhost it's working, but on another server I sometimes get the error :

> The operation has timed out

1. Is this a good web to check the website availability ?
2. What can be the reason of the TimeOut (firewall?) and how can I avoid it ?

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use `Webclient`.

And try to test the site with firefox, click <kbd>F12</kbd> and test if you have the same problem.

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("adresse");  
Response response = client.get();  

if (response.getStatus() == 200)
{  
    // Web service up and running  
}
else
{  
    // Web service is down 
}
```

Comment: 1- By convention, In C# method names start with UpperCase letter :) (create,get,getStatus) 2- WebClient doesn't have a static *Create* method. 3- WebClient instance doesn't have *Get*  method.